# How can I dynamically set the array object to java object

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I am new to java and I am stuck at one place.
I am taking xml request which is coming in array.

```
<PassengersDetails>
 <Passenger>
  <passesngerName>ABC</passesngerName>
  <passengerAge>25</passengerAge>
 </Passenger>
 <Passenger>
  <passesngerName>DEF</passesngerName>
  <passengerAge>28</passengerAge>
 </Passenger>
 <Passenger>
  <passesngerName>GHI</passesngerName>
  <passengerAge>48</passengerAge>
 </Passenger>
 <Passenger>
  <passesngerName>KLM</passesngerName>
  <passengerAge>18</passengerAge>
 </Passenger>
</PassengersDetails>
```

My xml object is getting turned into array like below.

```
Passenger [] passenger= passengersDetails.getPassenger();
```

And my java object looks like

```
class Passenger {
passengerName1;
passengerAge1;
passengerName2;
passengerAge2;
passengerName3;
passengerAge3;
passengerName4;
passengerAge4;
}
```

with setter and getter.

I wanted to set all the data from array in java object.
I am able to set it individually after checking if array is preset or not.

```
if(arr[0] != null){
setPassengerName1 = arr[0].getPassengerName;
setPassengerAge1 = arr[0].getPassengerAge;
}
if(arr[1] != null){
setPassengerName2 = arr[1].getPassengerName;
setPassengerAge2 = arr[1].getPassengerAge;
}....
```

How can I set passenger array into Passenger java object mentioned above.

But I wanted to know if there is any other way we can do this dynamically.

Something like in the same loop and setting it dynamically.

Comment: You should reconsider the modelling that lead to the `Passenger` class to not have 8 distinct fields that just happen to have similar names, but instead to use an array or a list of entries.

Comment: Hi @RalfKleberhoff , 
I have forgot to add <Passenger> tag between them.
Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Why then does your `Passenger` java class not correspond to the `<Passenger>` XML element? And in the class corresponding to `PassengerDetails` (the one you confusingly called `Passenger`), why don't you use a Java `Passenger[]` array or `List<Passenger>` list instead of the 8 individual fields?

Comment: Hi @RalfKleberhoff 
This is what is am trying to learn and do that if i have array elements coming from xml request how can i add all the details in 1 java object in very efficient way.

Comment: For a Java learning curve, I'd recommend to postpone XML to a later time, and for the moment concentrate on arrays, lists, `for` loops etc. And also forget "very efficient way". Think about efficiency only when you find efficiency problems. Code clarity should come first at top priority.

Comment: Study the first parts of the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) by Oracle, free of cost.

Answer (score 2):

Create a model class Passenger to hold the name and age only. Then you create an array that holds Passenger objects.

You then use:

```
getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier("propertyName", "string", getPackageName()))
```

to iterate through string resources, given you know how many passengers there are.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for answer. But i am bit confused that how can i do that.
I didn`t quite understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> But I wanted to know if there is any other way we can do this dynamically as we can get 0 or max 4 passenger elements in array.

Either:

- Start with one size of array, such as ten. As you place objects into the elements of the array, keep count. As you reach the limits of the array, create a new bigger array. Copy over from old array to new array. Discard old array. Repeat until done.
- Use a `List` implementation such as `ArrayList`.

Using a list.

```
List< Person > persons = new ArrayList<>() ;
```

Define a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) class to represent each person. You can declare the record as a separate class, a nested class, or as a local class (within a method).

```
record Person ( String name , int age ) {}
```

Add each person.

```
Person person = new Person( "Bob" , 42 ) ;
persons.add( person ) ;
```

When done, you may want to make an unmodifiable list to replace the modifiable one.

```
persons = List.of( persons ) ;
```